# Bootstrap - Fixed menu bar with scrollable content

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I found the following webpage: https://www.baronfunds.com/product-detail?fund=bdfix. When you scroll down, the item with OVERVIEW, PRICES & PERFORMANCE, etc, stays in place with the content scrollable. I want to do something similar.

I currently have:

[image]

I want to add a similar bar below the line with "Market Value".

I tried with the following html and css, and got this:

[image]

I want the top menu bar and the header section above the new menubar to stay place while scrolling. But here, the header section also scrolls.  That is, I want everyhing from Fixed Top Menu to scroll under the menu, while all above the menubar stays in place.

How to do this?

html:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            @Html.Partial("_company")
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="navbar">
    <a href="#home">Home</a>
    <a href="#news">News</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
</div>
<div class="main">
    <h1>Fixed Top Menu</h1>
    <h2>Scroll this page to see the effect</h2>
    <h2>The navigation bar will stay at the top of the page while scrolling</h2>

    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
</div>
```

css:

```
.navbar {
         overflow: hidden;
background-color: #333;
position: fixed;
top: 50;
width: 100%;
}

.navbar a {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
}

.main { padding: 16px; margin-top: 30px; height: 1500px; /* Used in this example to enable scrolling */ }
```

Comment: I am not sure I understand exactly what you are after here - it might help if you post a working example. Here's a couple of options for you though:
If you want the menu and everything above it to stay in place, you can use position fixed https://codepen.io/faktotum85/pen/KyMVoY
If you want just the menu to stay on top, with the section above sliding out of view you can apply position: sticky with top: 0px https://codepen.io/faktotum85/pen/wPWMyE

Comment: If I could post a working example, I would know how to do it. :) I want the Analysts/Coverage/ etc menubar and the header section starting with "Ryan Holdings" and ending with the <hr> below Market Value, Cost, etc, to always remain on the page when you scroll. And also the menubar with Home/News/Contact should always be available.

Comment: Well I meant a live demo of what you have so far  :) - does either of those codepens look like what you where after?

Comment: What codepens are you talking about. I don't see any links.

Comment: oh, there they are. I'll have a look.

Comment: This one here: https://codepen.io/faktotum85/pen/KyMVoY